# How to show a link in a text using a variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I use a link within a text like this:

```swift
Text("https://www.youtube.com")
```

As expected, the link shows up and I can press it and go to YouTube.

However, when I declare a variable first:

```swift
@State var link: String = "https://www.youtube.com"

// ...

Text(link)
```

The text is black and I can't press it to navigate to YouTube.

How can I make this text tappable as well, without using a link or url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is `LocalizedStringKey` which is the default for a `Text` which you are setting as a `String` in your `@State`.

You have to convert in one of 2 ways

At the `@State` level

```
@State var link: LocalizedStringKey = "https://www.youtube.com"
```

or in the `body`

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(link))
```

Whichever is best is up to you, likely option 2.

Comment: Option 2 did the job for me!

Comment: @BartVandeVeire since this answered your question can you click on the green checkmark to accept the answer?

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes apparently

Comment: do you know by any chance how I can style the link to be underlined? But only the link and not the normal text in the text?

Comment: @BartVandeVeire if adding `.underline(color: .accentColor)` doesn't work for you you would have to try `AttributedString` and add it via markdown.