# Localization of Text in SwiftUI does not work consistently

Tags: swift, string, xcode, swiftui, localizable.strings

I have been trying to localize a demo Sneaker App i am making for practice, i tried to localize some strings and they worked just fine, some others did not work but i managed to make them work using LocalizedStringKey(_). However this one line does not localize whatsoever, i cannot understand why.

here is the Text in the View:

```
Text("Size: \(orderItem.sneakerSize) | Color: \(orderItem.sneakerColor.colorToString())")
```

here is the localization for English in the Localizable.strings file:

```
"Size: %@ | Color: %@" = "Size: %@ | Color: %@";
```

and here is the localization for Arabic:

```
"Size: %@ | Color: %@" = "حجم: %@ | لون: %@";
```

yet when i try testing in the preview mode or in the actual build mode, it does not localize that string, can anyone explain??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a link in a text using a variable in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142448/how-to-show-a-link-in-a-text-using-a-variable-in-swiftui)

Comment: As i mentioned above, some worked using LocalizedStringKey() but this one does not for some reason, which is confusing.

Comment: What is the type of ```sneakerSize```? If it is a numeric value such as an ```Int``` then the placeholder should be something like ```%lld``` instead of ```%@```. Then I don't quite know how it works with forwards and backwards in the Arabic version, but is it correct that one placeholder is backwards (```@%```) and the other is forwards (```%@```)?

Comment: This made that line above actually work. can u also see why this has an issue: Text("\(orderItem.sneakerItem.discount)% off"), for arabic localization: "%d off" = "خصم %d"; but it does not work. any technical reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your additional comment that my suggestions helped. So I'll make them into an answer:

1. Check that the data types correspond correctly with the placeholders.

- If `sneakerSize` is a numeric type like `Int` then the placeholder needs to be something like `%lld` instead of `%@`.
- See [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) for more about specifiers.
- See also [Localization with String interpolation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64347096/20386264) for a convenient way to determine a placeholder by printing a `LocalizedStringKey`.

2. For the arabic version, check that there is no forwards/backwards mix-up. The example in your question includes `%@` as well as `@%`.
3. It seems that your localization keys are the same as the localized English versions. This might be making it difficult to tell, whether the English localizations are actually working or not. It might help to use simpler keys, such as `"SUMMARY %lld %@" = "Size: %lld | Color: %@";` so that you notice immediately if the English localization is not working either.
4. For the additional case that you added in your comment, you might need to be more specific with the formatting. I was able to get it working for English like this:

```swift
Text("DISCOUNT \(orderItem.sneakerItem.discount, specifier: "%.1f")")
```

```json
"DISCOUNT %.1f" = "You get %.1f%% off";
```